# Alternative to (deprecated) value attribute for li elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm currently working on a web application using HTML 5, CSS and JQuery. I have an unordered list (ul) for displaying page links, with each li element containing the page link. This list is created dynamically using jQuery.

What I would like to do is to have the list elements display only the page name in the link, but at the same time retain the full link path. For example, "http://www.foo.com/xyz/contactus" would be displayed as "contactus", but the li element would still "know" the full link path. For this purpose the value attribute of li would have been perfect, since i could set them like this:

```
var ul = $('<ul/>').attr('id', 'linkList');
for (var i = 0; i < linksOnPage.length; i++)  // linksOnPage is an array with all the links
    {
        var pgName = linksOnPage[i].toString().slice(steps[i].toString().lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

        // Create list element and append content
        var li = $('<li/>').text(pgName);    // Set the text to the page name
        li.attr('value', linksOnPage[i].toString());    // Set the value to the full link

        ul.append(li);
    }
```

This would create a list like:

```
<ul>
    <li value="http://www.foo.com/xyz/contactus">contactus</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Unfortunately the value attribute of li has been deprecated since HTML 4.01 (anyone know the rationale behind this? Seems pretty useful to me...).

So, I would like some advice on how to proceed. One option is to ignore the deprecation and use the value attribute anyway, since all the major browsers still support it, but I'm not very keen on using a deprecated feature and it just feels wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: _"What I would like to do is to have the list elements display only the page name in the link, but at the same time retain the full link path."_ - This is exactly what anchor tags are for, and anchor tags have the advantage of working for keyboard-only users who don't (or can't) use a mouse or other pointing device. It's good to follow standards with regard to deprecated attributes and so forth like you mentioned, but in my opinion it is much more important to follow accessibility standards...

Comment: @o.v. I think you can upvote a comment instead of write "agree" in a new comment...

Comment: @nnnnn: I agree, that hadn't actually occured to me. But I think I will stick to using lists for now, since I'm thinking of making it sortable using jQuery UI.

Comment: @gdoron: I did, but you can only do so once. Strong feeling of disapproval go the best of me.

Comment: William - Just put an anchor in each list item. You can still do all the list sorting and styling that you want, but it will be accessible too...

Comment: @nnnnnn: ok, will try that out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change from:

```
<li value="http://www.foo.com/xyz/contactus">contactus</li>
```

To:

```
<li data-value="http://www.foo.com/xyz/contactus">contactus</li>
```

`data-*` pattern is the new HTML5 way of keeping values in DOM elements.

You can get the values in one of the two ways:

```
$('#li-Id').data('value');
$('#li-Id').attr('data-value');
```

You can read [this blog post of John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) on those attributes.

jQuery [`data` function](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks! hmmm... seems like I have to wait 9 min until I can accept you answer for some reason

Comment: @William. I guess I'll have to wait until I can see the **$15** `:-)`

Answer (score 3):

Simply use a `data` attribute ([intro](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/); [longer tutorial](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/); [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes)):

```
<li data-path="http://www.foo.com/xyz/contactus">contactus</li>
```

As a plus, jQuery conveniently detects and exposes the values of such attributes through the [`.data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method.

Answer (score 1):

Even though `value` was deprecated, it could still be used and accessed w/JavaScript. You're only giving up validation status!

Alternatively you could either use `data-*` attributes (as I see others have suggested) or map values directly to DOM elements - since you're generating this markup at runtime you could just add a property like so (JS allowing you to do this is both a blessing and a curse):

```
li.someLinkPath = 'some url here';
//and in the click handler you could access this as
this.someLinkPath;
```

Still... if you're intending to use this for navigation, why not just use an anchor with an href?